# SO Files not getting generated in Android Studio with CMake

Tags: android, c++, cmake

We were using `Android.mk` & `Application.mk` NDK builds system. As we have common modules in the native layer which are being used by multiple projects, as the other projects are already supporting `CMakeLists.txt`, we are moving our Android project as well to CMake.

I have multiple static libraries in the sub-directories and the main directory (`jni/`) is generating the SO file. I have written `CMakeLists.txt` individually in the sub-directories and included them (add_subdirectory) in the `jni/CmakeLists.txt` file.
I see compilation is going through but not able to find the `.so` files either in **build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi** or **project/libs** folder. But I see the below message int he Android Studio Gralde

***Excerpt from the below:***

> -soname,liblogger.so -o /home/suman//build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi-v7a/liblogger.so Logger/CMakeFiles/logger.dir/src/Logger.cpp.o

***Full Command:***

> [2/2] : && /home/suman/Android/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi
>        --gcc-toolchain=/home/suman/Android/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 
>        --sysroot=/home/suman/Android/android-ndk/sysroot -fPIC 
>        -isystem /home/suman/Android/android-ndk/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi 
>        -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong 
>        -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as 
>        -marm -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -frtti -fexceptions 
>        -fvisibility=hidden -fstack-protector-all -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -Os -DNDEBUG
>        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a 
>        --sysroot /home/suman/Android/android-ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id 
>        -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack 
>        -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
>        -shared -Wl,-soname,liblogger.so -o /home/suman//build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi-v7a/liblogger.so Logger/CMakeFiles/logger.dir/src/Logger.cpp.o 
>        /home/suman/Android/android-ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/liblog.so -latomic -lm 
>        "/home/suman/Android/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libsupc++.a" 
>        "/home/suman/Android/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so" && :

Am I missing anything?

My folder structure is old Android build folder structure (Eclipse Folder Structure) - Flat structure. As project is pretty old and huge, didn't got migrated to new folder structure instead we are specifying the `sourceSets` in the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Got the issue fixed. 

I was setting some CMake variables before declaring the project(), due to which those settings were taking effect only in that file. It was not propagating to the the included_directories() and add_dependencies().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Got the issue fixed. I was setting some CMake variables before declaring the project(), due to which those settings were taking effect only in that file. It was not propagating to the the included_directories() and add_dependencies().

2) Don't declare any externalCMakeBuild { cppFlags } in the build.gradle file. It was messing up with NDK flags set by the build system.